# How to loop into the array that coming from a filter array?

Tags: javascript

Question, I have objects that I want to filter to get a specific value, but the problem is I need to map also a specific key to get all the value that need for my filter.

**Sample code**

```js
const arr = [{
    "invitedPeopleId": [
        {
            "isAdmin": false,
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "6127a0d12a55f41b380482c3",
        }
    ],
    "_id": "620be40739797c2064d9e26f",
    "projectId": {
        "_id": "620914a24d35c13d48c6be2a"
    },
    "taskCreatorId": {
        "isAdmin": true,
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "6127a0bb2a55f41b380482c0"
    },
    "taskName": "Create login page for user registration"
}]
    
const compare = '6127a0d12a55f41b380482c3';
    
arr.filter((x) => x.contact.map((y) => y.landline) === compare); // return empty
```

Thanks!

Comment: If `contact` was an object (not an array) with `landline` and `mobile` properties your data would be easier to navigate.

Comment: _"return empty"_ - Because you strictly compare an array against a string.

Comment: What is the expected output/result? Why `.filter()`?

Comment: Please try to either change `compare` as `321321` (and not `'321321'`) - OR - change `landline: 321321` to `landline: '321321'`. Because `321321` === `'321321'` may be false (the left-side is a number; whereas right-side is a string). Okay, the question is updated now.

Comment: Yeah, I know it will return empty, I forgot to add ''. But the arr is just a sample array.

Comment: Please try: `arr.filter(x => x.contact.filter(y => 'landline' in y).map(y => y.landline).includes(compare));`. Have tried with the sample array & this gets the first element (ie, `name: 'john'`) as result when searching for `'321321'`.

Comment: I use .filter because I have a list of task coming from my backend that I want to filter from the account id of the user that is currently login. It's just sample data that I include on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter by taking `contact` and ther if some value compares with the wanted one.

```js
const
    array = [{ _id: 1234, name: 'john', contact: [{ landline: '321321' }, { mobile: '123131' }] }, { _id: 1234, name: 'jane', contact: [{ landline: '5435353' }, { mobile: '5435353' }] }],
    compare = '321321',
    result = array.filter(({ contact }) =>
        contact.some(({ landline }) => landline === compare)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```